# TypeScript reflect-metadata Cannot find name 'Symbol'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I was reading this http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators

but, Error can not find `Symbol`, I do not know what it is `Symbol` if this is part of `reflect-metadata` or it was part of `reflect-metadata`

```
import "reflect-metadata"; //change for my path

const formatMetadataKey = Symbol("format");   <-- Cannot find name 'Symbol'.

function format(formatString: string) {
    return Reflect.metadata(formatMetadataKey, formatString);  <-- Work
}

function getFormat(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    return Reflect.getMetadata(formatMetadataKey, target, propertyKey); <-- Work
}
```

I have to import something else to Symbol?, or this has changed, someone knows I'm doing wrong.

---

### Update:

I think the solution is that [Amid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246398/typescript-reflect-metadata-cannot-find-name-symbol#36247238) comment on ES6, for some circumstance, my TSconfig, was not working all that well, but after some changes worked, but as a note saying.

- for example change or used es6 compiler option, it shows -> `Cannot find name 'Symbol'`
- if you compile error disappears, but if you make changes to the file, adds something more `variable ect` or a simple newline, the editor indicates the error mentioned earlier, but if you recompile the error disappears and so all the time but seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get more info about Symbol read this document: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

To get rid of the error: target ES6 instead of ES5.

Comment: thanks for link, but my compilerOptions is "target": "es6", from the beginning and follow the error in VSCode any ideas

Comment: That is strange because it is usual cause of the error. I have latest VSCode also and the code above does not produce any error if targeting ES6. And if changing to ES5 - error you describe appears.